# How can detect sound on webpage with JavaScript in PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, flash, audio, phantomjs

I need detect all sound in webpage with banners. How I can do this?
I look to PhantomJS, but can't find a API for browser sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhantomJS (1.x and 2) doesn't support either Flash, `<video>` or the `<audio>` element. There is no way to detect sound, because there isn't any.

From the [docs](http://phantomjs.org/supported-web-standards.html):

> Support for **plugins** (such as Flash) was dropped a long time ago.

and

> **Video and Audio** would require shipping a variety of different codecs.